# MySQL escape string causing data lenght error

Tags: php

I am trying to escape a string before inserting it to my DB, this string contains some characters that need to be escaped. 
For example :

```
 $mystring = "So, This is the string it's causing me headaches."
```

I want to insert this string into a field which has certain limit, say 50.
But the problem is when I use the mysql_real_escape_string function it adds the `\` to escape my single quote `'` which makes my strings length 51 and therefore I could not insert it into the DB .

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: The escaping is just for correct SQL literal format. The string `'foo\'bar'` has 7 characters, not 8.

Comment: @deceze That is not true, try it when you have a new line in your string then you will see what i mean.

Comment: So how exactly did the answer you accepted solve your problem?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string($mystring)`

Comment: There's no function called `mysql_real_escape`. If you mean `mysql_real_escape_string`, the OP is already doing that.

Comment: @Rishabh Because who said the OP is using Mysqli?

Comment: @deceze i think if not than the OP must use Mysqli as mysql.* are deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

The backslash is *not* part of the string. It's just part of the *string literal* in the SQL statement. Think about it like this:

```
CONCAT('a', 'b', 'c')
```

That's quite a lot of characters in the SQL statement, but the resulting string of this statement is just `abc` with 3 characters. In the same way, this:

```
'a\'c'
```

is the correctly formatted literal for the string `a'c` with three characters.

If your string is actually getting longer after escaping, you're probably escaping too often and the `\` becomes part of your actual string you're trying to store.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76008/1 for a demo. `'a\'c'` perfectly fits into a 3 char field.

Comment: Hi, the link to the demo is not working. Try to escape a string with a newline in it and you will get my problem.

Comment: The demo is working again now. And even with a line break there's no problem! `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('a\nb')` inserts the *three character string* "a<line break>b". That's only three actual characters.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use str_replace for the same,it always worked for me.

```
$mystring=str_replace("\'","'","$mystring");
$mystring=str_replace("'","\'","$mystring");
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?! You're replacing all `\'` by `'` and then again by `\'`?!

Comment: i used to do that for accidental insertion of '\',but i think one will work too.edited

Comment: So you're *unescaping* the string again? Whatever you think you're doing here, it's the entirely wrong approach for this problem.

Comment: @deceze i am having trouble understanding whatever you are saying but i am sure this is what the user asked who posted the question.

Comment: Again, please tell us **what this does.** When would you use it and *why*? Don't just throw code snippets out here the OP is supposed to use without explaining what it does.